# Does Lena suspect Supergirl's identity?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, supergirl-2015

Whether through the power of expectations or yet-unmentioned ["super-hypnosis",](https://blog.paxholley.net/2011/07/04/1-of-supermans-most-absurd-pre-crisis-super-powers/) people don't recognize Kara as Supergirl.

However, clearly people can guess her secret identity, because Cat Grant eventually did (despite Supergirl's deception with J'onn J'onzz). Now, Lena Luthor is both extremely intelligent and close friends with Kara, although she perhaps doesn't see her as often as Cat did.

Has there ever been any indication that Lena knows or suspects Supergirl's secret identity?

Comment: The rule of thumb for the show seems to be that nobody suspects Kara. Even in the recent episode where Brainy had blocked off his awareness of her identity, when Alex mentioned it, he literally laughed it off. He "remembered" a moment or two later, but there was never a "Oh, yeah, now that you mention it, how did I never see that?" moment.  It's just as well, because I've got no desire to see another "However will we convince them I'm not (hero)?" episode on any show, ever, in my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

There was an interview in which the executive producer Andrew Kreisberg and he confirmed that Lena does not know.

> In the wake of the Supergirl season 2 finale, and the discovery that Cat Grant knows Kara Danvers is Supergirl, people have begun to question whether or not Lena Luthor (Katie McGrath) also knows Kara's secret. TVLine spoke to Supergirl executive producer Andrew Kreisberg recently and asked that question, to which Kreisberg responded, "At the moment, Lena definitely thinks they’re two people."
> <sub>*- [Supergirl Producer Says Lena Luthor Doesn't Know Kara's Secret - ScreenRant](https://screenrant.com/supergirl-lena-luthor-kara-danvers-secret-identity/)*</sub>

So, as far as we know Kara's secret identity remains a secret from Lena Luthor. This hasnt changed since that interview which (as Adamant just pointed out) was almost 2 years ago.

> As for the big secret that Kara is hiding from her best friend—i.e. the fact that she is Supergirl—Benoist made it sound like Kara wouldn't be "coming out" anytime soon, despite this season's exploration of the theme of "passing" and how important it can be to have visible role models for marginalized identities.
> <sub>*- [Supergirl Season 4: When Will Kara Learn Lena's Secret? - Den Of Geek](https://www.denofgeek.com/us/tv/supergirl/277837/supergirl-season-4-when-will-kara-learn-lenas-secret)*</sub>

Comment: All praise the great god Status Quo.